# Page Reload/Refresh executes $(document).ready() on every page in jQuery Mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile

My jQuery mobile applications consists of multiple pages.

Whenever I reload a page, no matter which page in the application, `$(document).ready()` function is executed.   I expect it only to execute for the main page of the application.

What is going on?  I would like it only to run on the main page only.

Answer (score 1):

Please read

- http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0/docs/api/events.html

> **Important: Use pageInit(), not $(document).ready()**
>
> The first thing you learn in jQuery is to call code inside the
>   $(document).ready() function so everything will execute as soon as the
>   DOM is loaded. However, in jQuery Mobile, Ajax is used to load the
>   contents of each page into the DOM as you navigate, and the DOM ready
>   handler only executes for the first page. To execute code whenever a
>   new page is loaded and created, you can bind to the pageinit event.
>   This event is explained in detail at the bottom of this page.

Also for jQM page information please read

- http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0/docs/pages/index.html

Comment: Quoting from the text above: "DOM ready handler only executes for the first page",what I am trying to say is, that hitting reload button,no matter where are you in the application executes this $(document).ready function. Is this normal?

Comment: Using pageinit event leads to another frustrating problem.I need to download a json file,parse and save it and then use it.I want to download and save it in the pageinit handler and then use it in pageshow handler.What actually happening is that, the file is downloaded in pageinit handler, but instead of file being saved through the success handler, pageshow is fired inbetween the download and saved and then the success handler is called. I have verified it again and again, this behaviour is consistent.

Comment: I have checked with other events as well like pagebeforecreate,pagecreate,pageinit and pageshow and this behaviour is repeated

Comment: I would look at http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0/docs/pages/page-scripting.html and http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0/docs/pages/page-dynamic.html this second example works with JSON on building the page